# Raynaud's universal Tate elliptic curves

Tags: elliptic-curves, non-archimedean-fields

In the end of Section 9.2 of Bosch's book *[Lectures on Formal and Rigid Geometry](http://www.math.purdue.edu/~tongliu/seminar/rigid/Bosch.pdf)*, a rigid $S$-space $E_Q$ is constructed, for a variable $Q$ replacing the classical parameter $q\in k$. (Here $k$ is a non-archimedean field and $S=\mathrm{Spf}\mathbb Z[[Q]]$). Then $E_Q$ may be viewed as the family of all Tate elliptic curves by looking at the morphism $Z[[Q]] \to k^\circ, Q\mapsto q$.

(1) It looks interesting but the reference is missing in Bosch's book. Which one of Raynaud's paper is about this construction?

(2) Could we in some sense further generalize it by considering more than one variables, i.e. $S'=\mathbb Z[[Q_1,\dots, Q_k]]$? Notice that $S'$ seems still satisfy the condition $(N)$ required by Bosch (see p 162)

Comment: You may also look at Brian Conrad's notes http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/kmpaper.pdf I don't know the answer to Q2 but Z[[q]] makes sense as the moduli space of elliptic curves is 1-dimensional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Q1:** Michel Raynaud, [Géométrie analytique rigide d’après Tate, Kiehl...](http://www.numdam.org/article/MSMF_1974__39-40__319_0.pdf), Bull. Soc. Math. France, Mémoire **39-40**, p. 319-327 (1974).

Comment: As far as I know, the first place where the construction of the universal elliptic curve appears is in "Les schémas de modules de courbes elliptiques" by Deligne and Rapoport, in section VII.1., page 149, where they attribute it to Raynaud without any reference. This was in 1972, in the proceedings of the international summer school "Modular Functions of One Variable II".

Comment: I have the same question as the OP. It seems to me that the reference you give does not contain any mention of Tate universal elliptic curve. What Raynaud does there, is showing how to construct rigid spaces as generic fibers of formal schemes. Xarles comment seems to give the right reference, as long as there's nothing else by Raynaud to be found.